# SWIFT Comparison of String segue.identifier with a literal not working as expected

Tags: string, swift, comparison

I am trying to compare a String with a literal. When debugging it seems that both values "goToMCFDailySchedule3" match. However the execution flow seems to be jumping the if block. Any ideas why?

```
 println("value of the segue is: \(segue.identifier)")

 if segue.identifier? == "goToMCFDailySchedule3" {
      // Not entering here
 }
```

The result of the execution is:

```
 value of the segue is: Optional("goToMCFDailySchedule3")
 (lldb)
```

I am not sure why the println is show Optional. I guess it has to do with the nature of String Optionals.

Comment: I noticed that the segue.identifier is of type _NSCFString.

Comment: Guys, XCode crashed on me. I restarted and it seems to be working fine. It is also working with both of your solutions. I have no idea what the issue was. The command line debugger was not autocompleting and now it is. Not sure where the problem was. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier returns an optional value because the segue could have or not an identifier name. You should try to unwrap the returned optional value before the comparison to take place.

Do it this way:

```
if let identifier = segue.identifier {
  // Do the comparisons
}
```

This piece of code let you know if the identifier has indeed a value or not, if not, the program wont try to compare "its value" with anything and will pass the if declaration.

Comment: It does enter in the if but I can assure that the segue.identifier has value: "goToMCFDailySchedule3"
 {
  _core = {
    _baseAddress = 0x00007fa7b3a18b41
    _countAndFlags = 4611686018427387925
    _owner = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007fa7b3a18b30 -> 0x000000010530f4b8 (void *)0x000000010530f468: __NSCFString)
  }
}

Comment: If it enters the if is because the identifier has a value, and that the value is already unwrapped inside the identifier contant. After that, you can make your String comparisons to make sure the value is what you spect. What I mean is, first check if identifier has a value, then compare the constant identifier with you "goToMFCDailySchedule" string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the ? at the end of the segue identifier, try this:

```
if segue.identifier == "goToMCFDailySchedule3" {}
```

// Edited

If the log says that the identifier is optional try unwrap it, with exclamation mark:

`segue.identifier!`

Comment: No error. Just the identical result as before: value of the segue is: Optional("goToMCFDailySchedule3"). Meaning, the flow is not the expected one since it does not get in the if block

Comment: This is a way to compare segue's identifier with string. Make sure you haven't got any white spaces and the capital letters matters as well.

Comment: All checked. No spaces. Identical. Note the Optional("") in the console log.

Comment: You can try segue!.identifier, but I believe your identifier is blank, as shown in the log. Can you paste all log from console here: println("value of the segue is: \(segue.identifier)")

Comment: The segue is not blank as shown in the log: value of the segue is: Optional("goToMCFDailySchedule3")
You selected cell #0!

Comment: I have also checked it with the debugger prior to the if

Comment: If it's optional try unwrap it, with exclamation mark: segue.identifier!